# Move Custom List with attachments from SharePoint 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, upgrade-sharepoint

Hi I have a custom list with attachments in SharePoint 2013 and this custom list's New Item form modified in InfoPath 2013, Here what I want to move this list to SharePoint 2016.

I upgraded the list's content database to SharePoint 2016 Test server but i can not take the list backup it shows below error:

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException] [Cannot open file
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException] [Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.]
[6/27/2021 1:33:35 PM] [Debug]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)

Comment: Hi any ideas how i move simply custom list with attachments from sp2013 to sp 2016?

Comment: How are you trying to backup the list?

Comment: Hi tried by take backup of content database from SP 2013 to SP 2016 SQL Instance, after that when open list attachments not open it shows blank

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I suggest you use save your list as a template to migrate custom list with attachments from SharePoint 2013 to 2016.

There is the [same post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/453376/how-to-move-custom-list-with-attachments-from-shar.html) on the Q&A Forum, I suggest you can follow the progress of the post.

Comment: Hi when i save list as template list lost the created by user field value

Comment: i required who created the item also when i move to sp 2016